# Calculate the angles

Tags: geometry

It is given that that $AB \parallel CD,\ AC \parallel DE$ and $BD \parallel CE$ and the question is to give the value of the angles $x$ and $y$ if we know the value of the angles as shown in the picture. It is also known that $x,y \in \{20,30\}$.

[image]

Comment: You've used y to label 2 angles: 1 in C and 1 in A.

Comment: I don't think they have any specific values. Nothing stops $A$ and $B$ moving up and down along the fixed line $CA$ and $DB$.

Comment: Even so the only way you'd use the same variable to label them is if they are equivalent and you're solving for that specific situation.

Comment: @TerryChern: I think you misunderstood my comment.

Comment: @Terry Chern: I adjusted it, the 2nd y label is gone

Comment: @QuangHoang Oh, yeah I see what you mean now, after redrawing the diagram I realized that they are in fact the same angle. Edit: Actually not sure if same angle but I definitely get what you mean, so long as AB is parallel to DC it can move along those lines.

Comment: @Quang Hoang: I think you are right, I'm sorry for the bad question! But thanks for solving it.

Comment: Okay I'm really sorry I forgot to add that both angles are either 20 or 30 degrees, they can be the same though. (I'm very sorry about not adding this)

Comment: I solved it, thanks for the ideas you guys gave me! I wouldn't have found it without you guys.

Comment: My solution is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution to this problem. You can consider the following coordinates:

\begin{align*}
A &= \lambda\begin{pmatrix}-\cot20°\\1\end{pmatrix} &
B &= \lambda\begin{pmatrix}\cot30°\\1\end{pmatrix} \\
C &= \begin{pmatrix}\cot20°\\-1\end{pmatrix} &
D &= \begin{pmatrix}-\cot30°\\-1\end{pmatrix} \\
\end{align*}

You actually don't need $E$ at all. Now as you vary $\lambda$, the points $A$ and $B$ will move on their respective rays $CA$ resp. $DB$ arbitrarily. You have

\begin{align*}
\tan(x+30°)&=\frac{1+\lambda}{\cot30°-\lambda\cot20°} &
\tan(y+20°)&=\frac{1+\lambda}{\cot20°-\lambda\cot30°}
\end{align*}

So up front, neither angle is fixed. But if you assume $x,y\in\{20°,30°\}$ then you get contradictions:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
x&y&\lambda\\\hline
20°&\phantom08.334°&0.249\\
30°&12.122°&0.347\\
50°&20°\phantom{.000}&0.532\\
70°&30°\phantom{.000}&0.742
\end{array}$$

So as you see, you can't choose $x$ and $y$ from the set $\{20°,30°\}$ at the same time. You can't even choose them from the interval $[20°,30°]$ at the same time.

[image: Figure]